# return position of values that fall between a range in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

There are similar questions, but still I can't quite get the syntax correct
basically I want to return the locations of all items between my two specified values in the array. So for the below code it should return, 1, 2, 4, 6 as these are between the min and max.

I'm guessing I need to use the map function too create the new array and I use the ... to describe the range.

```
   let lowRange = 3.4
   let highRange = 7.8
   let mySampleArray = [3.5,6.3,9.3,5.7,10.2,2.2]


   let desiredRage = mySampleArray.map {lowRange...highRange} // this is the bit that's wrong

   print (desiredRage)
```

Comment: note that Swift collections indices are zero based

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed so you would expect 0, 1, 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter  your collection indices and pass a predicate to check if the desired range contains the element at the index position:

```
let low = 3.4
let high = 7.8
let array = [3.5, 6.3, 9.3, 5.7, 10.2, 2.2] 

let indices = array.indices.filter { low...high ~= array[$0] }  

print(indices)  // "[0, 1, 3]\n"
```

Comment: Haha here's an over-kill generic version: `zip(array.indices, array).compactMap { index, element in (low...high).contains(element) ? index : nil }` Works on non-randomly-accessibly collections